# How to tell if expression is evaluated at compile time or runtime?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have a rather big Map object and I want to have a separate list that has the keys sorted. This will be used in many other source files of my poject.

The question is about how do I know when a decalaration/definition is a compile time job. Where should I look to find if this is the case? I mean how to tell?

In the following example, is the list in the source file a compile time job or it happens at runtime?

Also, is there a way that I make the sorting operation at compile time?

```
// global.h    
extern QMap<int, QString> G_MAP;
extern QList<int> G_MAP_SKEYS_SORTED; 

// global.cpp
QMap<int, QString> G_MAP = { /* some hand filled (static) data */ };
QList<int> G_MAP_SKEYS_SORTED = G_MAP.keys();

// main.cpp
int mian() {
  // Somewhere I do the sort
  std::sort(G_ListRegistersSorted.begin(), G_ListRegistersSorted.end());
}
```

Comment: Just an idea: you could `static_assert` its size and let the compiler explain.

Comment: If construction of `QMap` (or `QList`), from `some data`, contains dynamic memory allocations, it can't, by definition, be done during compilation.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius the init list is filled by hand so it is not dynamic

Comment: `std::sort()` is `constexpr` only starting from C++20; so before (you tagged C++11) surely not.

Comment: The only thing in this example which is evaluated at compile time is initialization list: `{ /* some hand filled (static) data */ };`.

Comment: Do you really need the list to be sorted at compile time? Or do you just want to ensure that it is sorted as soon as you access it?

Comment: I think none of the QT stuff is performed at compile time. Whether init list is filled by hand or not makes no difference.

Comment: @pschill would be nice if it be a compile time but I guess no way ...

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't operate in terms of compile time and run time. This is an implementation territory. Others suggest constexpr, but expressions that are not constexpr *can* be evaluated at compile time, and expressions that are constexpr *do not have to be* evaluated at compile time (though they are in known implementations).

Comment: @DEKKER "_the init list is filled by hand so it is not dynamic_" I wasn't talking about initializer list. I was talking about constructors of `QMap`/`QList`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An expression is evaluated at compiletime if the result is assigned to a `constexpr` variable, used in a `static_assert` or `noexcept` statement, or used as a template parameter. This is called a constexpr context.

For example:

```
// Function which can calculate the fibbonacci sequence at compiletime
constexpr int fib(int n) {
    if(n == 0 || n == 1) return n;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2); 
}

int main() {
    // This one is calculated at compiletime
    constexpr int fib10_at_compiletime = fib(10); 

    // This one is calculated at runtime 
    // (unless the compiler was really aggressive when doing optimizations)
    int fib10_at_runtime = fib(10);    
}
```

In order to call a function or something at compiletime, it needs to be marked `constexpr`.

#### What can you do at compiletime?

**C++11:**

- Declare variables (but not modify them)
- Call other constexpr functions
- Call constexpr constructors (and default ones)
- Use carrays and `std::array`
- Use static_asserts and stuff
- `typedef` and `using` declarations

**C++14 additions:**

- You can also use lambdas now
- You can modify variables inside a constexpr function
- you can have constexpr member functions that change member variables
- you can pass references (the non-const kind) to constexpr functions

**C++20 additions:** (C++20 is coming out in 2020)

- You can allocate memory now
- You can call virtual functions now
- You can have `try-catch` blocks

#### Is `std::sort` constexpr?

In order to use a function in a constexpr context, it must be marked constexpr (which comes with a set of restrictions on what you can do in the function; these are discussed below). In C++11, `std::sort` isn’t constexpr because it breaks those restrictions (and it won’t be constexpr until C++20).

However, if you’re allowed to use C++14, you can write your own sorting function that works at compile time.

**Full overview:** https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: Thanks! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

> Also, is there a way that I make the sorting operation at compile time?

Short answer: no.

Long answer.

No because `std::sort()` is `constexpr` only from C++20 (you tagged C++11), because a `void` function (`std::sort()`) can't be `constexpr` in C++11, because `QMap` and `QList` aren't `constexpr` classes (if I'm not wrong), because you haven't declared `GMAP` and other object involved as `constexpr`, etc.

But, supposing to have a `MyMap` class defined `constexpr`, a `MyList` class declared `constexpr`, a `MySort()` function defined `constexpr`, you could write something similar (starting from C++14 because in C++11 you can't write a so complex `constexpr` function)

```
constexpr MyList foo ()
{
  MyMap mm { /* some values */ };

  MyList ml { ml.keys() };

  MySort(ml.begin(), ml.end());

  return ml;
}

// ...

constexpr auto ml_final { foo() };
```

Observe that `ml_final` is declared `constexpr`.

This is necessary to impose (pre C++20) the compiler to initialize the value compile-time, if possible, or give a compilation error, if impossible.